# How Does One Compound Their Stock Investment

Tags: stocks, investing

I was wondering if someone could explain the concept behind compounding your stock investments.  For example, let's say I buy 10 shares of a stock at 10 dollars each for a total of 100 dollars.  That same stock price the next day goes to 12.00 dollars per share.  You've made a 20 dollar profit.  If the stock drops the next day to 5 dollars, withdraw your profit of 20 dollars and then use it buy back into that same stock, but now 5 dollars a share.  You have just reinvested/spent your profit of 20 dollars to buy five more shares of this stock at 5 dollars per share.  Someone had explained this concept to me, and I want to make sure I understand it correctly.  Have I interpreted this correctly, and is it a solid concept?

Comment: If that's how stocks worked then the global economy would be in serious trouble or non-existent in the first place.

Comment: Generally when I hear people talking about that they're referring to re-investing stock *dividends*.

Comment: You can think of stock as analogous to some physical thing. It's not quite the same, but it can work to help understand this. Replace the word "shares" with "shirts" (or "used iPhones" or "gold") and try to make sense of it from there (assuming you can buy and sell shirts for the same price). If you have 10 shirts and the price of shirts increases, you'd still have 10 shirts. You'd need to sell them before you make any profit. There are also dividends, which would be comparable to being sent money for each shirt you own.

Comment: @NotThatGuy The dividend part of your analogy doesn't really work. It's more like, the shirt can shrink or grow in size (value) over time, and you can be given little torn off pieces of the shirt (dividends) but doing so will reduce the size (value) of the shirt. The important part to grasp is that dividends aren't "free" money, they come out of the company's distributable profits, and the fact that they have been paid to the shareholders means the company has less assets and is thus worth less money.

Comment: @JBentley You're missing the point of my analogy. Someone being willing to pay more for a shirt (stock) you own doesn't make that shirt bigger and dividends (usually) come in the form of money, not shirts (but you can possibly buy more shirts with it). The dividend part of my analogy would make sense if you add a brand name to the shirt and then have the dividends be the company sending money to all owners of shirts with their brand. The value of the shirt would be tied to the value of the brand / company, which decreases if they give away money.

Comment: @NotThatGuy Actually that's wrong. The price of a share represents the value of the underlying assets of the company, so generally if the share price has gone up it *is* because the company (shirt) is "bigger" than it was before e.g. it has more cash, more customers, higher return on investment than previously, etc. Dividends represent the fact that the company has chosen to part with some of its cash reserves, thus making the company smaller when it pays them out. Dividends are like pieces of shirts, because they are pieces of the company's assets.

Comment: @NotThatGuy Indeed with dividends there is a *direct* correlation between the size of the company's assets and the dividends it pays out. If a company pays out 5% of its assets in dividends, there are 5% less assets remaining afterwards.

Comment: Don't forget the fees.

Comment: @JBentley In my analogy the shirt is the *share* (and the company is still the company). That analogy is a lot closer to real life than having the shirt be the company, in terms of how shirts work, how stocks work and the separation between the company, the share and physical money. The only part it doesn't consider is stocks representing ownership, and most casual investors aren't going to buy a big enough portion of a company for ownership to matter. You're welcome to have your own different analogy.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

No, you've misinterpreted it.

When the stock drops to $5, your 10 shares are now worth $50. You have lost $50. The $20 profit you had on the previous day was a *potential* profit (called paper profit, or unrealized gain), based on selling at the $12 price, and you didn't take that offer.

If you *had* sold at $12, and kept the $120 as cash (ignoring commissions and taxes for this example) you could then have bought 24 shares at $5.

Comment: Good answer which precisely outlines the cause of the OP's confusion, rather than focusing on the exact terms used.

Comment: The common term is "paper profit", the technical term is "unrealized gain".

Comment: FWIW, ignoring fees is pretty reasonable these days, since we have online brokerages (e.g. Ameritrade, Schwab, etc.) with $0 commissions on stocks and ETFs.

Answer (score 10):

You're trying to "time the market" which has proven to be a losing strategy in the long run. In your scenraio, *if* you could sell partial shares (i.e. 1.67 to extract the $20 profit), then wait for the drop to $5 to buy 4 more, you'd have 12.33 shares. The problem is that those shares are now worth $5 each for a total of $61.67, so you *still* have an overall loss of ~$30.

If you had instead sold the whole lot at $12 *then* re-bought at $5, you'd still have just $120 worth of stock, but more shares (24 shares instead of 10).

But there are a lot of "what ifs": What if the stock *rose* the next day instead of falling? What if the stock fell the first day instead of rising? You can set up all types of theoretical scenarios to capture profit, but there's no way to predict what's going to happen to know if you should buy, sell, or hold.

That's not how "stock compounding" works. Stock returns work like compound interest because that's how the growth of the underlying companies tends to behave. Companies look at growth in relative terms, like 20% per year, so that growth "compounds" and thus the value of their stock compounds. There is no strategy needed to force stock investments to grow exponentially on average.

Comment: I see. makes sense.  based on what you are saying it almost sounds like it's best just to leave your investment be, ride the stock value roller coaster, then dump at the highest price?

Comment: @itsmevic It depends on your strategy. For long-term growth yes buy-and-hold is the best strategy, possibly with some tactical reallocation after large moves. There are "technical" traders that look for patterns in short-term movements, and some that "day trade" trying to catch these types of swings. There's not much evidence that either of then outperforms the overall market on average, though.

Comment: @NotThatGuy My point was that you could monetize the $20 gain, leaving the account with the initial $100 investment. You'd sell 1.67 shares to do that.

Comment: No, this is not "timing the market", it is buying low and selling high.  That is, when the stock goes to $12, you sell to lock in your profit (unless you think the price is likely to go higher).  Then you can invest the $120 in something else that you think is going to be profitable, which MIGHT be (but doesn't have to be) the same stock at $5.  Of course if you do this frequently, trading costs and bad guesses wipe out your profit.  If you do it reasonably well, though, you become the next Warren Buffet :-)

Comment: @jamesqf "buying low and selling high"/"unless you think the price is likely to go higher" - That is timing the market though. When the price goes up to $12, you don't know if it's high, or if it's about to go up even more. Maybe tomorrow it'll be $15 but you sold it to buy something else.

Comment: @itsmevic: The common advice is to spread your buys and sells, i.e. buy small amounts monthly when you're building capital, and sell small amounts monthly when you're withdrawing. This averages out price swings. It works nowadays because commissions are low.

Comment: @Matthew Crumley: This is why the claim that "timing the market doesn't work" is wrong. Sure, you never know if something (or the market in general) is at an absolute high, but you do know whether the price of stock X is higher or lower than when you bought it.  That is why it is a stock MARKET, after all, and not a fixed-income investment like a savings account.

Comment: @jamesqf the claim is not "timing the market doesn't work" - the claim is "on average, buy and hold is at least as good as timing the market" - selling high sometimes misses out on more gains, holding and riding the market, the poster is arguing, over time will beat attempts to time the market

Comment: @Stephen S: What you're missing is the time scale.  In the short term, yes, it does not pay to actively trade, at least as long as you're an ordinary investor.  In the long term... well, why are you investing in the market if you're not going to sell at some point?  So you can sign into your mutual funds' web sites and admire your net worth?

Answer (score 3):

> That same stock price the next day goes to $12.00 dollars per share.
>   You've made $20 dollar profit

On paper you have a profit. But you have to sell the shares to get the actual profit.

> If the stock drops the next day to $5 dollars, withdraw your profit of
>   $20 dollars and then use buy back into that same stock at now $5
>   dollars a share.

If you didn't sell yesterday then your 10 shares are worth $5 each for a value of $50. Now If you did sell yesterday then you can take your $120 in cash and buy 24 shares.

Of course you have to be able to time the market perfectly for this to work.

Stocks don't have compound growth.

Comment: Stocks do have compound growth. If a stock goes up 5% today and 5% tomorrow, someone who holds the stock gains 10.25%, not 10%.

Comment: @Mhoran_psprep I think the last sentence should be reworded for clarity - stocks *do* have compound growth, meaning that if you hold $100 in stock that goes up 5% this year, and 10% next year, and 6% the year after, your total ending value would be $100 * 1.05 * 1.1 * 1.06 = $122.43, instead of $100 * (1 + 5% + 10% + 6%) = $121. The point is that when calculating proportionate annual return, the value increase you get today, will enlarge the amount of value increase you get tomorrow.

Comment: But it doesn't grow like a savings account or CD does. It has a price that goes up, or goes down on a second by second basis. There is no committee that says that for the next year the value will go up by 10%. When the year is over you can say the gain or loss was x%.

Comment: Stocks do have compound growth, as long as you re-invest the dividends rather than spending them on other things. Growth-oriented mutual funds will do this for you automatically.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep Right but that's not what compounding means in the traditional sense. Compounding refers to the idea that gains are multiplicative, and that's why $100 growing at 10% / year is worth more than just earning $10 per year. The fact that the rate of growth is unknown in advance is a question of risk, not compounding.

Comment: Remember the question thought the price increase locked in profits, and they can always sell for the original price and buy at the new price. That belief goes away if you don't try and link stocks to compound growth.

Comment: @MikeScott However, stocks have compound growth even if they never pay out a dividend at all. A dividend that is not paid is retained profit and is added to the value of your stock in an equivalent way to if they were paid and you reinvested (ignoring the effect of taxes etc.).

Comment: Reinvested dividends only provide compound growth if share price appreciates.  If price drops, they accelerate losses.

Answer (score 3):

Compounding of an investment in a stock is not something that happens directly.

If you put money in an interest bearing account (such as a savings account, money market account, etc.) then each compounding period you are going to earn interest which is then credited to your account.  Then in the next period you are going to earn interest not only on your original deposit, but also on the interest earned in the first period.

When you purchase stock, the idea is that indirectly your investment will compound under the management whoever is running the company.  For instance, if the company sells widgets, they will reinvest some of their profits to buy more machines to make widgets so that now they can sell a larger number of widgets and earn greater profit.  This of course assumes that there is demand for additional widgets which nobody is satisfying, otherwise the extra widgets wont sell and the company may take a loss instead.